# how to get substring from string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in JQuery and I am trying to get substring from main string.I know there is function available for that but I don't know how to do my task using that.

here is my string

```
//Page 1
<p>
    <l>  30,  St.Bishop Road,  30min </l> 
    <l>  10,  St.Bishop Road,  10min </l>
</p>

//Page 2
<p> 
    <l>  30,  St.Bishop Road,  30min </l> 
    <l>  10,  St.Bishop Road,  10min </l>
</p>
```

I want to separate and store each `<p><p>` in array and same way for each `<p></p>` I want to store `<l></l>` value in array.

Keep in mind that this is not html element.this is string which I get from other task.

so How can I do this using jquery ?

Thanks

Comment: what you want to store? and which substring you are looking for?

Comment: show a test string and what you would like to get from that string

Comment: what is your string and what is your sub-string.....

Comment: I want how many <p></p> combination as well as for each combination how many <l></l> available

Comment: correct your markup as closing `<l>` should be like `</l>`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any valid HTML-like string into a jQuery object and you can then treat it as normal:

```
var $el = $('<p><l>30 St....');
console.log( $el.find('p') );
console.log( $el.find('p').length );
console.log( $el.find('l') );
console.log( $el.find('l').length );
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I wrote this before OP edit, his markup was not valid and he stated that it was not html.

I'm trying to keep this simple.
You don't need jQuery to do this, just use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

This does what you need:

```
var pieces = str.split('<p>');
```

Note that every piece will end with `</p>`, use [String.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to remove that:

```
var piece = pieces[0].substr(0, pieces[0].length-4));
```

Do the same for `<l>` elements.

Comment: I could be biased, but that feels much less simple than just having jQuery parse it into a selector :-)

Comment: Looking at the first post, it is :-)

Comment: this will create one unnecessary array element at first place which will always blank.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you expect this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   var c="<p> <l>  30,  St.Bishop Road,  30min <l> <l>  10,  St.Bishop"+ "Road,10min <l>"+
"</p>"+
"<p>"+ 
    "<l>  30,  St.Bishop Road,  30min <l>"+ 
    "<l>  10,  St.Bishop Road,  10min <l></p>";

    var b=c.split("<p>");
    $(b).each(function(data,value){
        if(data==1){

            var c=(value.split("<l>"))[1];
            alert(c);
        }
        if(data==2) {
            var d=(value.split("<l>"))[1];
            alert(d);
        }
    });



});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gtLrgort/)

Comment: His HTML is in a string, it's not part of the DOM

Comment: I want to create 2 arrays one is for <p></p> and one is for <l></l>.so this solution will not work.

Comment: @sandy,I changed the link,check it.